# Why does my BackgroundWorker stop?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

There is `BackgroundWorker` in `DoWork` art collection to create and `ParallelForeach`  processing.

```
private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    int cnt = (int) e.Argument;

    List<int[]> ListArrays = new List<int[]>();
    for (int i=0; i<cnt ; i++)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);
        int length = rnd.Next(5000, 100000);

        ListArrays.Add(new int[length]);

        for (int j = 0; j < ListArrays[i].Length; j++)
        {
            ListArrays[i][j] = rnd.Next(0, 1000000);
        }
    }

    int progress=0;

    Parallel.ForEach(ListArrays, item =>
        {

            if (_backgroundWorker != null)
            {
                if (_backgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress)
                {
                    _backgroundWorker.ReportProgress((int)(progress / (cnt / 100M)));

                }
                if (_stopThread)
                {
                    _busy.WaitOne();
                }
                if (_backgroundWorker.CancellationPending)
                {

                    e.Cancel = true;
                    return;
                }

                Worker worker = new Worker();
                worker.FindPrimes(item);
                CounterPrimes += worker.CounterPrimes;
                progress++;
            }
        });
}
```

There are buttons "Stop", "Pause" and "Resume". Just after the start stop is working properly. But if you take a "Pause" then continue after a stop button does not work, why?

```
AutoResetEvent _busy = new AutoResetEvent(false);
bool _stopThread; 
private void StopBtn_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   // _stopThread = false;
   //_busy.Set();
    _backgroundWorker.CancelAsync();
}

private void PauseBtn_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    PauseBtn.IsEnabled = false;
    _stopThread = true;
    ResumeBtn.IsEnabled = true;
}

private void ResumeBtn_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ResumeBtn.IsEnabled = false;
    PauseBtn.IsEnabled = true;
    _stopThread = false;
    _busy.Set();
}
```

[Russuan Question](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/505348/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-backgroundworker).

Comment: _But if you take a break, then continue after a stop button does not work, why?_
You said it yourself. STOP means STOP, there is no resume after. You need to pause it to be able to continue?

Comment: @Mafii Edit question, sorry

Comment: I am surprised there is `ru.stackoverflow`. Is it for *elite* (lol) group of Russian programmers? P.S.: I am russian-speaking, but will never go there, `ru.stackoverflow` is like `idontspeekenglishkkthxbai.stackoverflow`. English is useful.. i think.

Comment: Why such convoluted code? Why mix PLINQ *and* the obsolete BackgroundWorker *and* AutoResetEvent? In .NET 4.5+ (ie the only supported versions) you can use the `Progress<T>` class to report progress, a CancellationToken for cooperative cancellation. In fact, in this case you are using the BGW as a call to `Task.Run`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Can you show a simple example based on the progress<T>?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, `Parallel.ForEach` is TPL, not PLINQ. Otherwise you're spot-on.

Comment: As for why resume doesn't work - at least *part* of the problem is that you're blocking *all* `Parallel.ForEach` worker threads via `_busy.WaitOne()`, but only waking up one of them when you call `_busy.Set()`. The rest remain blocked. Meanwhile (this isn't a showstopper, but worth mentioning) `Parallel.ForEach`'s load balancer keeps throwing more thread pool threads at the problem which should eventually suffocate your thread pool (look at your app in Task Manager after you press Pause - you'll see the thread count growing by about 1 per second continuously).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `_backgroundWorker.CancelAsync()` it marks the `CancellationPending` flag as true, but it's your code's responsibility to periodically check if `CancellationPending` was marked and stop running.

In your code, you do check `CancellationPending`, but you only check it once, at the very beginning. The bulk of the work is being performed in the `Worker` class but it's only performed after your check, so that's why it will only work in the very beginning (regardless of whether you clicked on pause or not).
For the very same reason, your pause functionality will also only work at the very beginning since you only check your `_stopThread` flag once.

As an example solution, you can move the code that checks for the pause and the stop to a separate method:

```
private bool shouldStopWork(DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    _busy.WaitOne();        
    if (_backgroundWorker.CancellationPending)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

You can create a `Func` for this to encapsulate the event args: `Func<bool> shouldStop = () => shouldStopWork(e);`, and then pass this `Func` to your `Worker` class in its constructor, then have the `Worker` class call it periodically inside its `FindPrimes` method and exit the method if needed.

Another issue you have is that you are using `AutoResetEvent` which means that if you paused and then resumed, only one of the workers will awake, which is not what you want. You want all workers to awake, so you need to use `ManualResetEvent` instead. Also note that I removed the use for the `_stopThread` flag, it's not needed as there's already a flag inside the reset event, though you do need to reset the event on your pause clicked event: `_busy.Reset();`

Last point: like @Panagiotis Kanavos mentioned, `BackgroundWorker` is the old way of doing things, you can use async/await, tasks and the `Progress` class to report progress (an example: http://simplygenius.net/Article/AncillaryAsyncProgress), but note that this does not absolve you from the responsibility of periodically checking the need to cancel in your `Worker` class. The reason for this is that the only way to implement cancel without the help of the "other side" is to violently kill the thread but that can leave the application in an undetermined state. This is why `Thread.Abort` was deprecated as well.

Comment: Consider swapping the two parts of your answer. The bit re using `Auto/ManualResetEvent` is instrumental to fixing the problem, whereas the bulk of the answer preceding it (about supporting cooperative cancellation in `FindPrimes`) is more of a recommendation and may or may not make sense depending on how long each `FindPrimes` call takes.